# Javascript multiple class each function get selected class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, function

```
<div class="myclass effect1">bla bla</div>
<div class="myclass effect2">bla bla</div>
<div class="myclass effect3">bla bla</div>
<div class="myclass effect4">bla bla</div>

jQuery('.effect1, .effect2, .effect3, effect4').each( function()
        {       
               //I need to find which class is chosen?? 
                var newclass= Chosen class here will be here             
                jQuery(this).addClass('animated');

        }
        );
```

I've added information inside the code above. So how can I make this work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your iterator function, `this` will be the matching DOM element. That element has a `className` property with a space-delimited list of the classes on the element. There may well be more than one, unless you know in your markup that there will only be one.

If only one, just use `this.className` directly.

```
var newclass = this.className;
```

If more than one, you may find jQuery's [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) function useful:

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass('effect1')) {
    // ...
}
else if ($this.hasClass('effect2') {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

---

**But**, if you want to do different things depending on which class the element matched, it probably makes more sense to break up your query. Then you may not even need `each`, if you're trying to do something to all elements matching a given class.

For example:

```
jQuery(".effect1").animate({/*..settings for effect1..*/);
jQuery(".effect2").animate({/*..settings for effect2..*/);
jQuery(".effect3").animate({/*..settings for effect3..*/);
jQuery(".effect4").animate({/*..settings for effect4..*/);
```

---

From your comment, it sounds like you might want a dispatch map, like this:

```
var map = {
    effect1: function() { /* ...stuff for effect1... */ },
    effect2: function() { /* ...stuff for effect2... */ },
    // ...and so on...
};
```

You put that on the main level of your code.

Within the `each` (if you want to use `each`), you can identify the *first* `effectX` class in `this.className` like this:

```
var match = /effect\d/.exec(this.className);
var cls = match && match[0];
```

And then you can use your dispatch map with it:

```
if (cls) {
    map[cls].call(this);
}
```

That calls the function, making `this` within the function the DOM element. Or you could pass it as an argument instead:

```
if (cls) {
    map[cls](this);
}
```

...and have your dispatch functions accept it, e.g. `effect1: function(element) {...`

Comment: But the thing is there are about 30 class elements that can be selected so I need more simple way to do it instead of writing 30 times if else I suppose.

Comment: @AdnanBekir: `switch`? Or a dispatching map?

Comment: @AdnanBekir: I've added an example of a dispatch map.